# Create Gridview Template field and dropdownlist dynamically for AutoGenerateColumns ="true" for 300 columns

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I want to enable inline header search in gridview , for this I need Template fields which I cannot write on design page as I am generating columns from database.

I need functionality like this......

[here](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Filter-ASPNet-GridView-using-DropDownList.aspx)

Please, suggest me any other way if this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom class that inherits the `ITemplate` interface. Override the InstantiateIn method and create controls required for this template as [described here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0e39s2ck.aspx).
Assing an instance of your class to [TemplateField.HeaderTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield.headertemplate(v=vs.110).aspx) property of your grid in the `GridView.Init` event handler. Alternatively, try using a [third-party component](https://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/Filtering/FilterRow.aspx) that has such a feature.